# CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) too slow - Tips to Improve performance?

Tags: excel, vba, performance, listobject

Im trying to automate a report that have 5 different information sources. Im trying to make a UNION of different tables into a single one using ListObjects, everything is working fine except when I copy the first column of the first ListObject. It takes about 2 minutes to copy the first column, the next columns takes less than 1 second.

Every time I run the VBA script I delete all the rows of the destination table to start the VBA script with a ListObject with 0 rows.

I'll try to explain how it works:

```
Sub ProcesarPresupuesto() 
'This is the first macro that process and copy the information of the first source

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'<Here> I add several columns and process the information of this first source, I keep all the rows as values using the Function: AddColumnFormula (at the end of this example). I think this is not causing the problem.

'Then I fill all the Blanks Cells to avoid having empty cells in my final table.
Sheets("Origin").Select
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
On Error Resume Next
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "Null"
On Error GoTo 0

'When I have the ListObject ready I start copying the columns to the destination

Sheets("Destination").Select
Range("A1").Select
While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
Call CopyColumn("Origin", ActiveCell.Value, "Destination")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Wend

End Sub
```

I think this should be very fast. If I delete only the values of the Destination ListObject and keep the rows empty, the first column is copied immediatly so I think the problem is related on how Excel calculate the first rows to be added to the ListObject. Is there a better way to copy a column when the table is empty? Am I doing something really wrong?.

This is the Function CopyColumn

```
Function CopyColumn(Origin, ColumnName, Destination)
    Range(Origin & "[[" & ColumnName & "]]").Copy Destination:=Range(Destination & "[[" & ColumnName & "]]")
End Function
```

This is the Function I use to process the columns

```
Function AddColumnFormula(DestinationSheet, TableName, ColumnName, Value)

Set NewColumn = Sheets(DestinationSheet).ListObjects(TableName).ListColumns.Add
NewColumn.Name = ColumnName

Set Rango = Range(TableName & "[[" & ColumnName & "]]")
Rango.Value = Value
Rango.Copy
Rango.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

End Function
```

Thanks in advance for your time and answers

Comment: What is the address of this range? `Range(Origin & "[[" & ColumnName & "]]")`?  Add `MsgBox Range(Origin & "[[" & ColumnName & "]]").Address` and let's see what it shows.

Comment: Thanks @DavidZemens for your help, it gives me the Range($A$2:$A$42174) which is the range of the first column in the source. It appears to be ok.

Comment: Hmmmm. I am running your code on 45,000 rows of data, it takes less than a second to copy 7 columns (with screenupdating = False) and less than 2 seconds with screenupdating = True...

Comment: HI @DavidZemens I tried during the weekend to work on this, and I havent been lucky. Here is an example of my file. I deleted some worksheets that are not used for this Macro. The strange thing here is that when I test it on another computer it works better but it is still slow. The Macro is Called: ProcesarPresupuesto and it is in the Module "GenerarReporte" [link](http://miguelvalencia.com/Reportupload.xlsb)

Comment: I ran it once, it was a little slow but I did not time it. Then I made some changes to the ProcessarPresupuesto, it took 1m16s. I tried a few more things with varying success, most recent took 3m13s but most executions are ~2 minutes each.  In that attempt I put in some Debug.Print statements and I *think* the problem is with the `...CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` -- this statement took 2m53s to evaluate.  I will look at this a little longer but I think that is the culprit: both `CurrentRegion` and `SpecialCells` are expensive operations. There may be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some testing with the file you provided.  It was slow but I did not time it at first.  I saw some opportunities to revise the code which *might* improve performance, and the timer took 1 minute 16 seconds.

I tried a few more things with varying success, using `Debug.Print` statements to inform me what part of the code was running and how long they were taking.   Most executions were about 2 minutes each, the slowest was 3m13s.

In that final 3m13s attempt, I had narrowed my focus to the:

`...CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)`

This is suspect because both `CurrentRegion` and `SpecialCells` methods can be expensive. Combining them seemed like a recipe for disaster.

I figured I would try a simple iteration, just to compare performance, and to my surprise, I am able to do a simple `For each` loop over 42,000 rows and 32 columns of data, and this would execute consistently in about 14 seconds for a total run-time of about 30 seconds.

Here is the code I use for the loop:

```
Dim cl As Range
'Debug.Print "For each ..." & Format(Now(), "hh:mm:ss")
For Each cl In wsP.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
    If cl.Value = vbNullString Then cl.Value = "Null"
Next
'Debug.Print "End loop " & Format(Now(), "hh:mm:ss")
```

Here are my last three results:

```
31 seconds:    
    Commencar a 21:09:25
    For each ...21:09:38
    End loop 21:09:52
    CopiarColumnaListOBjectaVacia...21:09:52
    Finito : 5/5/2014 9:09:56 PM

30 seconds:    
    Commencar a 21:10:23
    For each ...21:10:36
    End loop 21:10:49
    CopiarColumnaListOBjectaVacia...21:10:49
    Finito : 5/5/2014 9:10:53 PM

34 seconds:    
    Commencar a 21:18:42
    For each ...21:18:55
    End loop 21:19:09
    CopiarColumna... 21:19:09
    Finito : 5/5/2014 9:19:16 PM
```

I have saved the revised version of the XLSB on Google Docs, so that you may review in its entirety.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1v0s8ldwHRYZWhuTmRuaDJoMzQ/edit?usp=sharing

As I said, I did make some changes to this subroutine and also to `RenombraColumna`, but in hindsight while those may offer some efficiencies, I think the root of the problem was with `CurrentRegion.SpecialCells`.

I hope you do not mind that I revised the title of this question to be more suitable for the particular problem.  As originally stated, the question was not likely to help others with the *same* symptoms.